# Should I store static configuration in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am building a react/redux web app and am wondering where I should static configuration information that never changes (while the webapp is running anyway).

[This is the data in question](https://github.com/askmike/gekko/blob/0b8df89f747be2fb0de620bf21ad63982d154e60/exchanges.js#L34)

This information is used in different parts of the app, for example: there is a form where you are able to select any item out of the main array, and by doing so populating another select field with properties of the selected array:

```
<select>Choose an exchange</select>
<select>Choose a market (that is available in the above exchange)</select>
```

This would lend itself nicely to some reducer logic (that sets `state.markets` based on what is selected in the first `select`), but should it filter based on other state in the tree, or just load the data in a closure inside the reducer (keeping everything unrelated outside of state tree)? Or is this not state at all (and should the container load this file in and filter based on a single `state.exchange` state prop)?

When the form is filled in the result will be handled like:

```
{exchange: 'a', market: 'b'}
```

So that would be state too (I guess?)

Comment: If that data you posted never changes, I would just leave it as a module the way you have it. then you can import it wherever you need to read any of those fields.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My understanding of `redux` is that we should only be storing *stateful* data in the `store`, that is, data that is subject to change. Static data by definition does not have state, and therefore does not need to be tracked as such.

As a result, I typically have a `/common/app-const.js` file where I store these types of static objects. In your case, you can simply move all the static data from `exchange.js` into a common file that you then `import` wherever you need it.

**/common/app-const.js**

```
export default {
    markets: [
          { pair: ['USD', 'BTC'], minimalOrder: { amount: 0.01, unit: 'asset' } },
          { pair: ['RUR', 'BTC'], minimalOrder: { amount: 0.01, unit: 'asset' } },
          { pair: ['EUR', 'BTC'], minimalOrder: { amount: 0.01, unit: 'asset' } },
          ...
}
```

I understand your approach however, it would be nice to simply inject your data, by way of `connect()` via `react-redux`, however its a bit more straightforward to just `import` the static data from a file where needed.

Comment: A word on your last paragraph, while it's more 'straightforward' the import statement to the static data file creates a very hard dependency on that file. Redux provides a form of dependency injection in that regard.